# Add Date to Clocks on Multiple Time zones

Tags: javascript, html, time, timezone

I'm seeking help on how I can add the current date for X,Y,Z time zones.

**JavaScript:**

```
const clocks = document.getElementsByClassName("clock");

function updateClocks() {
  for (let clock of clocks) {
    let timezone = clock.dataset.timezone;
    let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      timeZone: timezone
    });
    clock.textContent = time;
  }
}

// Update every minute:
setInterval(updateClocks, 60000);
updateClocks();
```

**Html**

```
<span class="clock" data-timezone="Europe/London">05:55 PM</span>
<span class="clock" data-timezone="Asia/Seoul">08:55 AM</span>
```

I get the time with no problem, but I can't figure out how I set the current date for those time zones.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date()
```

The object returns the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
const getColonTimeFromDate = date => date.toTimeString().slice(0, 8);

getColonTimeFromDate(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Finally figured it out:

```
const clocks = document.getElementsByClassName("clock");

function updateClocks() {
    for (let clock of clocks) {
        let timezone = clock.dataset.timezone;
        let time = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {

            weekday: "long",
              month: "short",
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            second: '2-digit',
            timeZone: timezone
        });
        clock.textContent = time;
    }
}
```

just had to add 
weekday: "long",
              month: "short",

output: Oct Wednesday, 05:38:17 AM